# Declaring a string with fixed size and then taking input

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int length;
    cin>>length;
    string s(length,'\0');
    cin>>s;
    cout<<s;
}
```

int the code above firstly im taking a int length and then using it to define the size of the string but the issue is that when i `cin>>s` after defining length the string still takes more char's than length 
i.e OUTPUT->

```
3
Hello
Hello
```

this should not happen after defining length of the string,

Comment: Read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want:

```
std::string s(length, '\0');
std::cin.get(s.data(), s.size());
```

Comment: `s.c_str()` returns a pointer to const data, so you can't fill the string using that pointer. Use `s.data()` (C++17 and later) or `&s[0]` to get a pointer to writable memory. Otherwise, use a `std::vector<char>` instead, and then copy it to a `std::string` afterwards.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/) says:

> `istream& operator>> (istream& is, string& str);`
>
> Extract string from stream
>
> Extracts a string from the input stream `is`, storing the sequence in `str`, which is overwritten (**the previous value of `str` is replaced**).
>   Each extracted character is appended to the string as if its member `push_back` was called.

So, when you're doing:

```
cin>>s;
```

the contents of the string are being replaced with your input that can be of any size because characters are being appended to the string as if `push_back` was called.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, it should. You misintepret meaning of instructions you give, without regard to documentation.

Long answer: You had created an empty string with reservation of 3 chars. `operator>>` assigned new value to `s`. Old value, a 3-character capable string is lost.